# How to query current date in mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net

```
cmd = New MySqlCommand("Select SUM(CAST(REPLACE(totalamountdue, ',','') as decimal (16, 8))) from tbl_sold where datetransaction = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%M/%d/%y')", con)
   
Dim salesday As Integer = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
       
salesofthedaytxt.Text = FormatNumber(salesday)
```

just want to get the sum of totalamountdue to the current date of datetransaction

Sample format of my date in table is 04/19/2022 .

ERROR:"System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Integer' is not valid.'

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select 
    SUM(CAST(REPLACE(totalamountdue, ',','') as decimal (16, 8))) 
From tbl_sold 
Where salesday = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%m/%d/%y');
```

[SQL sandbox here](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql57/af3ed241a75c730e4ad42f82f749dc55/)

Comment: i did of what you've said, but now it display error, what's wrong with the code

Comment: What error you got?

Comment: ERROR:"System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Integer' is not valid.'